# Is there a way to find the position of a special character '\n' in a file in C?

Tags: c, lseek

I want to find the position of a '\n' in a file and print out the remaining characters after \n

I've tried to use lseek to find the number of times '\n' occurred but I cannot seem to find the position at which the special character '\n' occurs

I've also tried using **strok** to break the particular file down and **lseek** to find the position of the last character

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 512
//path name is the file that is being accessed
void printLines(char *initPathName, char *initBuffer, int initnumberRead)
{   
int fileDescriptor; 
int numOfBreaks =0;

char *pathName=initPathName;
fileDescriptor = open(pathName, O_RDONLY);

lseek(fileDescriptor,initnumberRead * -1, SEEK_END); 

int size =  read(fileDescriptor, initBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH);
initBuffer[size] = '\0';
char *token = strtok(initBuffer, "\\\n\r"); 

for(int i= 0;token !=NULL;i++)
{
    write(2,token, strlen(token));
    write(2,"\n", 2);
            write(2,"a break occured\n", 17);
    token = strtok(NULL,"\\\n\r"); 
}
close(fileDescriptor);
}
```

### input

```
./program some.txt -l 3 // this prints the number of lines to be printed and separated with line breaks
```

### What is should do

three lines printed

```
some text 
a break occured
some text 
a break occured
some text 
a break occured
```

### output

instead it prints the number of characters in the file and formats it based on when a \n occurred

```
.. ext 
a break occured
```

Comment: I think you are thinking about this somewhat backwards. Every line in a file will be terminated with `'\n'`. So rather than searching for a `'\n'`, you can simply read the file with `fgets` and a sufficient sized buffer, or use POSIX `getline` and let it allocate and simply count lines discarding however many you want to skip and keeping the lines you want. If you want the character count up to the `'\n'`, you can simply read a line and use `strcspn (buffer, "\n");`

Comment: Note that `strtok(initBuffer, "\\\n\r");` looks for any of 3 characters — backslash, newline, carriage return.  Also: `write(2,"a break occured\n", 17);` writes a null byte to standard error (and "occurred" has two r's).

Comment: I think you need to show an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
See also
[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).  The calling code, and `MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH` should be shown too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler alright thank you, I'll fix up my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to find the position of a '\n' in a file and print out the remaining characters after \n

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long find_first_newline_then_print(FILE *fn) {
  int ch;
  long long pos = 0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && ch != '\n') ++pos;
  if (ch == EOF) return -1;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) fputc(ch, stdout);
  return pos + 1;
}
```